# Is it possible to persist cookies between visual studio debug sessions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, authentication, cookies

I have an authentication cookie that gets set after I hit a login screen in my local environment. That cookie has been set to be persistent and has been given a timeout period of 7 days in the future.

[image]

When I end my debug session and start debugging after another build the cookie is not present. This happens for every browser. Is there a way to get Visual Studio to remember the persistent cookie after a debug session completes?

Comment: Some cookies definitely persist. I just opened a debug browser by running a project in VS2017, logged on to another application, which set a cookie. Closed VS2017. Reopened the project and the cookie was still there. Your issue might be a bit more subtle

Comment: How are you reading and writing the Cookies? You aren't falling into the rookie mistake of using the Response Object? Do you use a `Form` tag? Are you using a Developer Tool to determine the cookie has been lost or please show the code?

Comment: Please add some code showing how you are reading and writing cookies

Comment: are you using Asp.Net Identity?  regardless there should be a persist flag (Identity there is).  using identity and setting the persist flag works for me.  I know what works for me isn't working for you.  update your answer with more info so we can provide better assistance.  you have no code snippets, just a screen shot of something useless

Comment: Have you tried running the project on your local IIS server? You can set it up by going to project properties -> Web -> servers -> Local IIS -> [you project url]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found was to make it so that new instances of .NET Core MVC would not open up in a brand new window, but an existing one. I changed one setting

1)Tools menu
2)Options...
3)Debugging > General
4)Uncheck "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET"

And when I run the app with F5 an instance fires up in an existing instance of chrome and I can reuse the cookies that are already in existence. With that box checked it always opens into a new instance of chrome and cookies are not present.

Comment: Already unchecked, but Visual Studio still keeps opening new Chrome window for each debug session.

Answer (score -3):

Let’s have a quick look how to make cookies as persistent

```
    //Creting a Cookie Object
 HttpCookie _userInfoCookies = new HttpCookie("UserInfo");

//Setting values inside it
 _userInfoCookies["UserName"] = "Abhijit";
 _userInfoCookies["UserColor"] = "Red";
 _userInfoCookies["Expire"] = "5 Days";

 //Adding Expire Time of cookies
  _userInfoCookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);

 //Adding cookies to current web response
 Response.Cookies.Add(_userInfoCookies);
```

Now once you have set with the Cookies expires time , it will be stored in hard drive until expires or user manually delete or clear all the cookies. If you want your cookies need to be expires before the expiration time that you have mentioned earlier, you just need to override the cookies information.

```
HttpCookie _userInfoCookies = new HttpCookie("UserInfo");
   //Adding Expire Time of cookies before existing cookies time
   _userInfoCookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
   //Adding cookies to current web response
   Response.Cookies.Add(_userInfoCookies);
```

So Just Work on Expiration.
and take a look at [This](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31914/Beginner-s-Guide-To-ASP-NET-Cookies)

Comment: I actually already am setting the expiration of the cookie. If you check the image above I have the expiration set 7 days in the future. I used the same code you listed above, created the cookie, stopped visual studio, and then started it up again. The cookie did not persist. VS continues to delete them after a debug session.

Comment: So Wrote them into the file along debugging.